# JSX element type 'Route' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm replacing code from javascript to typescript. But, fail building.
- `JSX element type 'Router' does not have any construct or call signatures.`
- `JSX element type 'Switch' does not have any construct or call signatures.`
- `JSX element type 'Route' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

How do I fix this error?

wrong code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import Counter from './containers/Container';
import store from './stores/store';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';


const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/counter" component={Counter} />
        <Route path="/counter/:id" component={Counter} />
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

and same error occurred when I used `import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';` .

Comment: What version of react router is this?

Comment: "react-router": "^4.1.1",
"@types/react-router": "^4.0.12",

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you have to install react-router-dom as stated [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom). Then do something like this,

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Counter from './containers/Container';
import store from './stores/store';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/counter" component={Counter} />
                <Route path="/invalid/path" component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
      , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Note that you have to provide the path to each route. The default Route configuration would be something like this. This should come at last since it matches the urls in the given order.

```
<Route path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
```

The component can simply be written like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class PostsIndex extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Index page
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Anyway I have not used type scripts with react since it is seldom used. But the given approach above should work.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding !

Comment: Ravindra Ranwala, Thank you for your answe.  
I tried install react-router-dom and modified code like this.  
but, same error occured.
`Counter ` `Counter` `NotFound` those types are function.  
Is it the cause of the bug?

Comment: Could you update the question with the latest code, so that I can look into that. It seems you  have imported Counter component from a wrong path, or you may now have exported the module. Please update the question with the latest error message and code so that I can look into this further.

Comment: I just noted that you have same Counter component for two different paths. Remove one of them and try that out again. I updated answ.er

Comment: I have done the same as in the proposed code. Still see the same errors as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, after change from

```
export class Provider extends React.Component<ProviderProps> { }
```

to

```
export class Provider extends React.Component<ProviderProps, void> { }
```

in index.d.ts, the problem gone. 
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I can not thank you enough for words!
Bug fixed after modified node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts like this.

before

```
export class MemoryRouter extends React.Component<MemoryRouterProps> { }
export class Prompt extends React.Component<PromptProps> { }
export class Redirect extends React.Component<RedirectProps> { }
export class Route extends React.Component<RouteProps> { }
export class Router extends React.Component<RouterProps> { }
export class StaticRouter extends React.Component<StaticRouterProps> { }
```

after

```
export class MemoryRouter extends React.Component<MemoryRouterProps, void> { }
export class Prompt extends React.Component<PromptProps, void> { }
export class Redirect extends React.Component<RedirectProps, void> { }
export class Route extends React.Component<RouteProps, void> { }
export class Router extends React.Component<RouterProps, void> { }
export class StaticRouter extends React.Component<StaticRouterProps, void> { }
```

This is "@types/react-router": "^4.0.12" 's bug.

Comment: You should definitely not be editing the contents of the `node_modules` folder manually.